# How can I make a single filter on Google Data Studio for multiple columns which contain dichotomus variable?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a database that looks like this:

| Var1 | Var2 | Tag 1 | Tag 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Local1 | V1 | 0 | 1 |
| Local2 | V2 | 1 | 0 |
| Local3 | V3 | 1 | 0 |
| Local4 | V4 | 0 | 1 |

In  Google Data Studio Report [here](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/20857f9d-924f-4e70-a0f4-121b5b368184); how do I put a single  filter box where I can select the tag (title of the column of multiple columns) and only the rows that have a 1 in that rage of columns shows up?

The return of the filter would look like this When the filter selects Tag 1

| Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- |
| Local2 | V2 |
| Local3 | V3 |

And the return would look like this when the filter selects Tag 2

| Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- |
| Local1 | V1 |
| Local4 | V4 |

Sample data is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fjS6E01GPrhWvv8L4cs0RpcWYRgQ5pQxXyBBYUQwysw/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

You set up an example for two columns, but in your sample you have many. Therefore, I show how to do it for two columns by selecting a number. But for the real case a parameter with a text list would be more user friendly, so they could see what they are selecting. All columns in the function are queried, so keep the costs for that in mind.

There is the need to use a parameter, lets call it `tag_selected`.

[image]

Create a field `tag_filter` with the columns you would like to select

```
case when tag_selected=1 then Anti-Corruption and Integrity
when tag_selected=2 then Audits
else 1
end
```

[image]

Finally create a filter to the table with the condition `tag_filter` =1

[image]